# SD card writing with an nodeMCu ESP8266

Tags: text, arduino, esp8266, sd-card, nodemcu

I am trying to write some data to an SD card with a nodeMCU ESP8266 card.
Here is the basic code I use :

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

const int CS_PIN = D8;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if(!SD.begin(CS_PIN)){
    Serial.println("not this time");
  } else {
  File test = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  test.print("hello");
  test.close();
  Serial.println("ok");
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

Here are the wiring I made :

```
SD       nodeMCU
-----------------
GND        GND
VCC        3.3V
MISO       D6
MOSI       D7
SCK        D5
CS         D8
```

The SD card format is FAT, as it is asked in the SD.h documentation.

The program can't even open the SD card...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: does the esp8266 start? D8 is a boot configuration pin and must be LOW at boot. try a different pin as CS.

Comment: What would be the best pin, if there is a difference between other pins ? Should I also change other pins ?

Comment: to test use D1.

Comment: It doesn't change anything :(

Comment: what SD card adapter do yo use? do you have a link to a shop site?

Comment: I bought this shield : https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07SBR9NL1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: it has level conversion from 5 V to 3.3 V and should be powered with 5 V. try to power it from the 5 V pin on NodeMcu. or connect the SD card directly without a level conversion (simple way is ti solder jumper wires to a large-to-micro SD adapter)

Comment: YES IT WORKS ! Thank you you saved me from hours of pain